# Why are all apps disabled?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

All of my apps are gone.  All of the built-in, external storage apps had disappeared.

It happened when my phone's battery was dead, and when I turned it on after charging, everything was gone.  I can see my apps in the application manager but it shows that all of the apps are disabled and I can do nothing.
I cant even add a picture here.

Phone: Samsung Galaxy Grandneo Plus

Comment: Try booting into [safe-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) and see if you can re-enable the apps from there. Wiping cache (that's the app cache, not Dalvik/ART) cannot hurt either; all recoveries offer that (see our [recovery-mode tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) for how to enter recovery, and for other details).

Answer (score 1):

All I know about *"disabled apps"* is when the device is booted into Safe Mode.

Maybe your device is on **Safe Mode**.  This happened, when you *"accidentally"* pressed a button on your device while booting up.  Try checking, if it has a *"Safe Mode"* displayed on your screen, usually at the corners.

Rebooting the device normally would surely fix the problem.